# left join not providing the object properties i want

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm sure I'm doing something stupid, but my AR code

```
@comments = Comment.find(:all, :limit => 10,
                         :joins => "LEFT JOIN `users` ON comments.user_id = users.id",
                         :select => 'comments.*, users.theme')
```

Is returning the correct sql:

```
SELECT comments.*, users.theme from comments LEFT JOIN users on comments.user_id = users.id
```

and when I put it into a mysql, I get the results I want, but when I try to access `@comment.theme` (in an each loop on @comments) after the above AR call is made, `theme` is not there.

So, is there something special I have to do to the Comments model to allow joins to populate the associated columns?  I thought that Rails would just add them as properties I could dot-grab.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
@comments.each do |comment|
  puts comment.theme
end
```

All the fields are in the array @comments, as Object type Comment, and the field names are as used in the select, with no regard to their original source.

Good luck.

Comment: Interesting. When I called `awesome_print` on the @comments list, nothing appeared.  I guess the values are lazy-loaded or something?

Comment: Thanks for accepting the answer. Please up vote as well if it worked for you.